# How do I fix Multer-Gridfs-Storage error "Error creating storage engine. At least one of url or db option must be provided"?

Tags: heroku, multer, gridfs, storage-engines

As I am trying to deploy my app to Heroku, I get the error "Error creating storage engine. At least one of url or db option must be provided." in my heroku logs. However, I get no errors while developing and testing the app in my IDE.

Here is my error log:

```
...
2020-10-17T05:24:18.106601+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Error creating storage engine. At least one of url or db option must be provided.
2020-10-17T05:24:18.106602+00:00 app[web.1]: at new GridFSStorage (/app/node_modules/multer-gridfs-storage/lib/gridfs.js:59:10)
2020-10-17T05:24:18.106602+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/config/multer.js:7:17)
2020-10-17T05:24:18.106603+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1015:30)
2020-10-17T05:24:18.106604+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1035:10)
2020-10-17T05:24:18.106604+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:32)
2020-10-17T05:24:18.106605+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
2020-10-17T05:24:18.106605+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:903:19)
2020-10-17T05:24:18.106605+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
2020-10-17T05:24:18.106606+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:9:16)
2020-10-17T05:24:18.106607+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1015:30)
...
```

Here is my code for multer:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const path = require('path');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const multer  = require('multer');
const GridFsStorage = require('multer-gridfs-storage');

const storage = new GridFsStorage({
  url: process.env.URI,
  options: { useUnifiedTopology: true },
  file: (req, file) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      crypto.randomBytes(16, async (err, buf) => {
        if (err) return reject(err);

        const filename = buf.toString('hex') + path.extname(file.originalname);

        const fileInfo = { filename, bucketName: 'uploads' };
        
        resolve(fileInfo);
      });
    });
  }
});

const upload = multer({ storage });

module.exports = upload;
```

My `process.env.URI` variable is in the form: `URI=mongodb+srv://...`

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error was actually due to my environment variables. I had to set them up in Heroku for the application to read them (I was relying on my `.env` file, but of course the `.gitignore` file will prevent the file from being pushed to Heroku master).

Answer (score 0):

For someone using mongodb as database. I am using the mongodb connection string and I refer to it via `.env` variable. Since `.gitignore` is not pushing this `.env` variable, it happens that this connection string is missing. You can fix this by basically adding your connection string back into your `.env` file.